# Explicit template for lambda: operator() or template operator()?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

Given a generic lambda. I want to call an explicit version of it, perhaps because the compiler would deduce a different type. In the example I use `double` as the type I'm calling the lambda with, but I actually want it to be the `int` version.

I didn't have success by just adding `<T>`to the lambda, so I googled and I found 2 versions on Stack Overflow on how to achieve this: one is using `operator()<T>` and the other is `template operator()<T>`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    auto lambda = [](auto p){ return p; };
    auto d = lambda(3.3);
    std::cout << d << "\n";
    auto i = lambda.operator()<int>(3.3);
    std::cout << i << "\n";
    auto t = lambda.template operator()<int>(3.3);
    std::cout << t << "\n";
}
```

Try this online: https://godbolt.org/z/abWYh8K1x

To understand the difference between the two versions, I searched the C++23 Draft N4868 for "template operator" and I found an example in §13.7.3, but it occurs in a comment and only uses `operator()<T>`.

Is `template operator()<T>` actually standard C++? If there is a difference between `operator()<T>` and `template operator()<T>`, what is it?

Comment: an example where `template` is needed https://godbolt.org/z/zxbjqn4sW. Its not needed in your example. I didnt spot it in the dupe yet but answers there should explain it

Comment: *"Is `template operator()<T>` actually standard C++? ..."* Yes. See [C++ - Why is the 'template' keyword required here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60062567/c-why-is-the-template-keyword-required-here)

Comment: I didnt check the standard, but I'd try with search term "dependent name"

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai: dependent names, [temp.dep] (§13.8.3 in N4868). Thanks. Always good to know the proper name of things.